# Asp.net Page access through IP address control

Tags: asp.net, security

Is it possible to create a page in asp.net that allow the access to a user that has a defined IPaddres? My goal is to add a page "test" (not linked to my website) and I want to define a rule that only a specified IP address can get the access.
How can I implement this throught asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting the page(s) in a separate folder and password protect it, then, give the password to your user, so they may access the content. You could go as far as password protecting each file. This helps if your website is password protected or has a login.

You could also create a sub-domain for that user specifically.

These are just a few. I'm sure you'll get better suggestions here on SO!

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. At the moment I only have a test page that is not linked to the website so you must type the entire URL of the page if you want to see it. I have no clue about how to implement the password for the folder or for single file. The website does not have login or needs to be protected from password. I just need to ass this condition in the way we can have a test page that is not visible to the frontside but is "hide" for programming

Comment: I see now (I think) what you're trying to achieve. I updated my answer to reflect this, describing the possibility to check the IsLocal property of the current Request.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there are a lot of other and arguably better ways to grant access to a page if what you really want is for a specific "user" or "group" to have access, but assuming that your really want the access control to be based on IP, the answer may still be dependent on peripheral concerns such as what web server you are using. IIS for example has some features for IP based security that you could check out.

Assuming though that you really, really want to check IPs and that you want to do it in code, you would find information about the calling environment in the Request of the current HttpContext, i.e. `context.Request.UserHostAddress`.

If you want to reject calls based on this information, you should probably do that as early as possible. In the HttpApplication.BeginRequest event you could check if the call is targeted for the page in question and reject the request if the UserHostAddress is not to your liking.

If you prefer to make this control in the actual page, do it in some early page event.

To manage the acceptable IP(s), rather than hard coding them into your checking code, I suggest you work with a `ConfigurationSection` or similar. Your checking code could be something similar to:

```
var authorizedIps =
    authorizedIpConfiguration.Split(',').Select(ipString => ipString.Trim()).ToList();

isValid = authorizedIps.Any()
    && authorizedIps.Contains(context.Request.UserHostAddress);
```

If the check fails, you should alter the response accordingly, i.e. at least set its status code to 401 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

**NB:** There are a lot of things to consider when implementing security features, and the general recommendation would probably stand as "don't do it" - it's so easy to falter. Try to use well proven concepts and "standard implementations" if possible. The above example should not in itself be considered to provide a "secure" solution, as there are generally speaking many ways that restricted data can leak from you solution.

**EDIT:** From you comment to the answer given by nocturns2 it seems you want to restrict access to the local computer? If so, then there is a much easier and cleaner solution: Just check the `Request.IsLocal` property. It will return true only for requests originating from the local computer, see [HttpRequest.IsLocal Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

(Also, you should really make sure that this "debug page" is not at all published when deploying your solution. If you manage that properly and securely, then perhaps you do not even need the access check any more. If you want debugging options in a "live" environment, you should probably look to `HttpContext.Current.Trace` or some other logging functionality.)

Comment: I would like to restrict address (URL), to an IPADDRESS not to a single computer.I want to input the IPaddress of the router where some hosts are connected in the way that only them can have access to this page at the same time and "live".I would avoid them to use the "local webserver".In this was the page is live but not visible to anybody since is not linked. Even you type the exactly URL of the page you don't have the IP address that has been specified. By the way you gave me a lot of good suggestion which I am going throught.

Comment: I am well aware that an IP is not necessarily bound to a specific computer. Your approach is shaky, and it is sometimes difficult for me to understand what you mean, but even so, I'm confident that with regard to IP based security the text above contains clues to the solution to whatever problem you have. I hope it will prove to be of help to you.

Comment: sorry for the caps lock. I appricciate your help. I was just trying to be more precise. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a programmatic solution. However, I would use IIS functions to block the access. Less code, easier to configure and no hassle on your developement/test environment.

Assumption: you are using IIS since it is ASP.NET. But other webservers should have similar solutions.

You can add IP restrictions to the directory (meaning you would have to put your page in a separate directory). Example here: http://www.therealtimeweb.com/index.cfm/2012/10/18/iis7-restrict-by-ip

Comment: You mean from the control panel of IIS ? because I don't use the local webserver. I do changes by editing the files directly from the ftp.  But thanks for the tips.

Comment: You can add a web dot config file to the directory you want to protect. With it, you can allow and deny several entities, (i.e., by user, by roles, etc.), for that directory and it's subdirectories. Caution: your host might not allow you to change certain things, I would do some testing first.